# Converting numbers to string using IValueConverter or string property in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have several Labels in my View.xaml that display some kind number (e.g `<Label Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>`).
These are backed in the Model.cs by Properties (e.g. `public decimal OnHandQuantity { get; set; }`).
And exposed through the ViewModel.cs (e.g. `public decimal Quantity { get; set; }`).

I now want the labels to display the text in a specific format, depending on which localization the user chooses in the settings or even a custom format.

**What would be the prefered method to achieve this?**

I currently pend between two methods: Changing the ViewModel.Quantity to a string and formatting it when i set it (e.g. `item.Quantity = _stocks[0].OnHandQuantity.ToString("N", App.Settings.Language.NumberFormat);`). Or i could implement a `DecimalToStringConverter : IValueConverter` and use it for the labels that show numbers.

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of my proposed solutions?**

Answer (score 0):

> What are the advantages and disadvantages of your proposed solutions?

Actually , these two ways are all wisely. However,if you have other logic about the text of labels,binding the value in ViewModel is better.Otherwise you could set the BindingMode as `TwoWay`and get it in your ViewModel.